# Matching keys to JSONObject

Tags: java, json, key

```
    try {
        String json = jsonObject.getJSONObject("default").getString("text");
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "JSON value: " + json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Where jsonObject =

> {"google.sent_time":1489972321131,"google.message_id":"0:1489972321143879%1ad00caef9fd7ecd","default":"{\n
>   \"condition\" : \"normal”,\n    \"priority\" : \"normal\",\n
>   \"time_to_live\" : 0,\n    \"notification\" : {\n        \"body\" :
>   “Body of notification”,\n        \"title\" : \"TEST TITLE”,\n
>   \"icon\" : “ic_launcher”\n    },\n    \"data\" : {\n
>   “PriorityLevel” : 1,\n        \"text\" : \"TEST TEXT”\n    }\n}"}

Headbanging for over an hour now. How do I output the string belonging to the key "text"?

Error log

> 03-19 21:37:20.653 7499-7640/com.amazon.mysampleapp W/System.err:
>   org.json.JSONException: Value { 03-19 21:37:20.653
>   7499-7640/com.amazon.mysampleapp W/System.err:     "condition" :
>   "normal”, 03-19 21:37:20.653 7499-7640/com.amazon.mysampleapp
>   W/System.err:     "priority" : "normal", 03-19 21:37:20.653
>   7499-7640/com.amazon.mysampleapp W/System.err:     "time_to_live" : 0,
>   03-19 21:37:20.653 7499-7640/com.amazon.mysampleapp W/System.err:
>   "notification" : { 03-19 21:37:20.653 7499-7640/com.amazon.mysampleapp
>   W/System.err:         "body" : “Body of notification”,
>   03-19 21:37:20.653 7499-7640/com.amazon.mysampleapp W/System.err:
>   "title" : "TEST TITLE”, 03-19 21:37:20.653
>   7499-7640/com.amazon.mysampleapp W/System.err:         "icon" :
>   “ic_launcher” 03-19 21:37:20.653 7499-7640/com.amazon.mysampleapp
>   W/System.err:     }, 03-19 21:37:20.653
>   7499-7640/com.amazon.mysampleapp W/System.err:     "data" : { 03-19
>   21:37:20.653 7499-7640/com.amazon.mysampleapp W/System.err:
>   “PriorityLevel” : 1, 03-19 21:37:20.653 7499-7640/com.amazon.mysampleapp
>   W/System.err:         "text" : "TEST TEXT” 03-19 21:37:20.653
>   7499-7640/com.amazon.mysampleapp W/System.err:     } 03-19
>   21:37:20.653 7499-7640/com.amazon.mysampleapp W/System.err: } at
>   default of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
>   03-19 21:37:20.653 7499-7640/com.amazon.mysampleapp W/System.err:
>   at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:100) 03-19 21:37:20.653
>   7499-7640/com.amazon.mysampleapp W/System.err:     at
>   org.json.JSONObject.getJSONObject(JSONObject.java:613) 03-19
>   21:37:20.653 7499-7640/com.amazon.mysampleapp W/System.err:     at
>   com.mysampleapp.PushListenerService.onMessageReceived(PushListenerService.java:126)
>   03-19 21:37:20.653 7499-7640/com.amazon.mysampleapp W/System.err:
>   at com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmListenerService.zzo(Unknown Source)
>   03-19 21:37:20.653 7499-7640/com.amazon.mysampleapp W/System.err:
>   at com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmListenerService.zzn(Unknown Source)
>   03-19 21:37:20.653 7499-7640/com.amazon.mysampleapp W/System.err:
>   at com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmListenerService.zzm(Unknown Source)
>   03-19 21:37:20.653 7499-7640/com.amazon.mysampleapp W/System.err:
>   at com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmListenerService.zza(Unknown Source)
>   03-19 21:37:20.653 7499-7640/com.amazon.mysampleapp W/System.err:
>   at com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmListenerService$1.run(Unknown Source)
>   03-19 21:37:20.653 7499-7640/com.amazon.mysampleapp W/System.err:
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>   03-19 21:37:20.653 7499-7640/com.amazon.mysampleapp W/System.err:
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>   03-19 21:37:20.653 7499-7640/com.amazon.mysampleapp W/System.err:
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 03-19 21:48:29.043
>   7499-7506/com.amazon.mysampleapp W/art: Suspending all threads took:
>   9.113ms

Comment: How is this not working? Show your error messages.

Comment: Error log added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with regex in java. It's not ideal, but works.

```
String message = getMessage(data);
String pattern = "\"text\".:.\"([^\"]+)”";
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher m = r.matcher(message);
m.find();
Log.d(LOG_TAG, m.group(1));
```